# How to retrieve data from perfectly working phone without a touchscreen?

Tags: 2.2-froyo

I have a Motorola XT615, which fell into water a year ago. Everything works fine, except the touchscreen which is completely unresponsive. I've kept it because inside it has the log of dozens of last.fm scrobbles that I don't want to lose (and I'm a perfectionist when it comes to logging the music I've listened to). I asked the dev of the scrobbling app about how to get this, and he said I'd need to retrieve the "sql lite database".

Phone:

1. Is Froyo
2. Is rooted
3. Probably not in USB debug mode
4. Has physical volume buttons that I can use (could be remapped somehow?)
5. Is recognized by the computer, but not in USB mode (can't enable it without a touchscreen)

If there is no solution via software, and before I start trying to track down a digitizer for this really old, abandoned phone, is there any way I can pick up the insides of it, and put it in another phone, in order to get all of this info?

Answer (score 0):

Use a keyboard to put it into USB mode and enable USB debugging. After that, you could clone entire phone from PC if you want to due to root. You could also use ADB if the phone supports ADB without debugging.

Comment: Thanks for responding Don't think it supports a keyboard... or at least I read about how OTG USB mouse were not available for Froyo without installing some custom ROM or something like that. Don't think ADB will work either - I tried listing the devices and it appears as "offline". I ended up opening the phone, and disconnecting the screen to see if reconnecting it would do anything, but now I can't reconnect it and the phone is all screwed from the opening... good riddance I guess.